# What is the equivalent of CreateMemStorage() in OpenCV3 in python?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am referring code from opencv 2.4 and trying to migrate to opencv 3.1. I could not find a complete migration guideline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CreateMemStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html#creatememstorage), as well as many other function to manage dynamic C structures, are now **obsolete**. This was still present in OpenCV 2.4.12, but is removed in OpenCV 3.

They refer to C api, which was abandoned something like 5 years ago.
Now you should use C++ api. As reported from the [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html):

> *[`CreateMemStorage` and similar functions are from]* OpenCV 1.x API for creating growable sequences and other dynamic data structures allocated in CvMemStorage. If you use the new C++, **Python**, Java etc interface, you will unlikely need this functionality. Use std::vector or other high-level data structures.

OpenCV provides a [transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0) that can be helpful.