# cv2 equivalent attributes to cv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have come across this [link](https://gist.github.com/philipcristiano/5805662) for face detection and image cropping. I would like to use this script but I have cv2 install and only import cv2 works but not import cv.

How can I convert the cv functions in the following function to cv2 functions?

```
def faces_from_pil_image(pil_image):
    "Return a list of (x,y,h,w) tuples for faces detected in the PIL image"
    storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
    facial_features = cv.Load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml', storage=storage)
    cv_im = cv.CreateImageHeader(pil_image.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv.SetData(cv_im, pil_image.tostring())
    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(cv_im, facial_features, storage)
    # faces includes a `neighbors` field that we aren't going to use here
    return [f[0] for f in faces]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
import cv2

storage = cv2.cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
```

or

```
from cv2 import *

storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
```

Comment: Error:   `File "face_detect.py", line 55, in faces_from_pil_image
    storage = cv2.cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'`

Comment: What is your `cv2.__version__` ? Which Version of Python?

Comment: Python 3.4. cv2 3.1.0-dev

Comment: The code is for OpenCv 2.x not 3.x! Many C-Interface functions like CreateMemStorage are removed in OpenCv 3.1. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810518/what-is-the-equivalent-of-creatememstorage-in-opencv3-in-python